# Calling a script with x3270 -script

Tags: linux, bash, 3270

I have an old script which is used to scrape information from an IBM server via x3270.  However, I can't get it to work correctly.  This is how I'm calling it:

```
/usr/X11R6/bin/x3270 -script -model 3279-2 -geom +110+160 -efont 3270-20 'Script( "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/x3270/qmon_script.sh" )'
```

I get an x3270 window and the following error message:  Hostname syntax error:  Multiple port names

The script I'm calling handles all the connection details, but x3270 appears to be confused and is thinking 'Script( "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/x3270/qmon_script.sh" )' is the hostname (which is obviously not correct).

I've been unable to find any good examples on how to call a script through x3270 like this.  Any ideas?

Comment: No personal experience with this, but the [man page](http://x3270.bgp.nu/Unix/x3270-man.html) seems to be saying that the script should be on standard input, not as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for `x3270`](http://x3270.bgp.nu/Unix/x3270-man.html):

> -script
>
> Causes x3270 to read commands from standard input, with the results written to standard
>   output. The protocol for these commands is documented in x3270-script(1).

So it doesn't allow giving the script itself on the command line. Instead you're supposed to supply the script through standard input. You probably want either:

```
echo 'Script( "/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/x3270/qmon_script.sh" )' | /usr/X11R6/bin/x3270 -script -model 3279-2 -geom +110+160 -efont 3270-20
```

Or maybe:

```
/usr/X11R6/bin/x3270 -script -model 3279-2 -geom +110+160 -efont 3270-20 < /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/x3270/qmon_script.sh
```